# print only one/desired value in for/foreach loop

Tags: perl

I have part of the code (program which needs to calculate sum of open files on system for specified users):

```
for my $opt_u (@opt_u){
    my $generic_acc_open = `/usr/sbin/lsof -u $opt_u  | /usr/bin/wc -l`;
    chomp ($generic_acc_open);
    #print "$open";
    print "Number of open files for users:$opt_u[0]=$generic_acc_open**$opt_u[1]=$generic_acc_open\n;"
}
```

where `opt_u` is argument for users specified on cli.

My problem is when i run a program (`./proc_limit -u root jenkins`) i am getting output like this:

> `Number of open files for users:root=85**jenkins=85`
>
> `;Number of open files for users:root=13**jenkins=13`

I am trying to get output in one line, probably it is not possible because array is specified with arguments in this case two times(for two users). Is it possible with for/foreach loop or i should use something else to get output in one line like this:

> `Number of open files for users:root=85**jenkins=13`

Comment: Drop the `\n` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```perl
print "Number of open files for users:" ;
for my $opt_u (@opt_u){
  my $generic_acc_open = `/usr/sbin/lsof -u $opt_u  | /usr/bin/wc -l`;
  chomp ($generic_acc_open);
  print " $opt_u=$generic_acc_open";
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently trying to print out results for two different queries using the same variable, `$generic_acc_open`.

You need to get the results for each user and store them separately. Here's one possible way to do it that will work for any number of users:

```
print "Number of open files for users: ",
    join(" ** ", 
        map { my $n = `/usr/sbin/lsof -u $_  | /usr/bin/wc -l`;
              $n =~ s/\s+//g;
              "$_ = $n"
        } @opt_u ), "\n";
```

Output:

> `Number of open files for users: anonymous = 5548 ** jenkins = 42 ** root = 0`

Explanation:

```
print "Number of open files for users: ",
  # join every member of the array with " ** "
  join(" ** ",
    # map applies the expressions within the braces to each member of the array @opt_u
    # map produces an array as output, which is acted upon by the join function
    map {
      # get number of open files for user $_
      my $n = `/usr/sbin/lsof -u $_  | /usr/bin/wc -l`; 
      # remove whitespace from the answer
      $n =~ s/\s+//g;
      # print out the user, $_, and the number of open files, $n
      "$_ = $n" } @opt_u ),
"\n";
```

To print the total number of files, keep a tally of how many files are open and print it at the end of the line:

```
my $sum;
print "Number of open files for users: ",
    join(" ** ", 
        map { my $n = `/usr/sbin/lsof -u $_  | /usr/bin/wc -l`;
              $n =~ s/\s+//g;
              $sum += $n;
              "$_ = $n"
        } @opt_u ), "; total files: $sum\n";
```

Comment: for example how can i add one more value for sumarized numbers of open files? something like this : my $sum += $n;  ?